# Restangular request is halted when using _.debounce() and angular v1.1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, underscore.js, restangular

I've encountered a strange bug in angular v1.1.5 when using `_.debounce()` and `restangular`.
It doesn't fire the restangular request until the next `debounce` is called, very strange. I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw6X0Nq61EBrAsrFty3d?p=preview) demo for your viewing pleasure.

I tested it with the newest version of angular and it works. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade. So I was wondering if someone knew what was going on and a possible workaround.

This is the troublesome directive (don't mind the request target, I just needed some public API to query against):

```
app.directive('delayed', function(Restangular) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, c) {
      var request = function(someValue) {
        $('#expected-output').append('Delayed execution: ' + someValue + '<br/>');
        $('#actual-output').append('Delayed execution: ' + someValue + '<br/>');

        var params = {
          client_id: 'GY4W5CTM20CNKUYWQ0AO1FZEW3H0SMAS1EI5QEHRL3RJZVYG',
          client_secret: 'CKWHBUAKO2MQF4OTWCKLPIS4WQOZLKBRFKVP5NSVTHHWXXXH'
        };
        var venueId = '40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3';

        Restangular.one("venues", venueId).get(params)
          .then(function(data) {
            $('#actual-output').append('Success: ' + someValue + '<br/>');
          });
        $('#expected-output').append('Success: ' + someValue + '<br/>');
      };
      var delayedRequest = _.debounce(request, 1000);

      c.$parsers.unshift(function(someValue) {
        delayedRequest(someValue);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[If you missed the demo link, well here it is again :)](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw6X0Nq61EBrAsrFty3d?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling debounce, you need to add `safeApply` to the call.

You can't just add `$apply` because for one of the callers of the function, it might be called inmediately, but for the rest it won't. If it's called inmediately, calling $apply will fail, therefore safeApply just runs $apply if needed.

You need to run $apply because in most cases, `debounce` is a different "javascript turn" or event which ANgularJS knows nothing about (Like if you were using a jQuery plugin).

I forked your example and now it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/527s0KwAnyZwGmnhUm4f